# get contents from array and show in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, stanford-nlp

I am going through the iOS development videos by Stanford and am doing the assignment 1.

I am having a problem with task 4:

> Add a new text label (UILabel) to your user-interface which shows everything that
>   has been sent to the brain (separated by spaces). For example, if the user has entered
>   6.3 Enter 5 + 2 *, this new text label would show 6.3 5 + 2 *. A good place
>   to put this label is to make it a thin strip above the display text label. Don’t forget to
>   have the C button clear this too. All of the code for this task should be in your
>   Controller (no changes to your Model are required for this one). You do not have to
>   display an unlimited number of operations and operands, just a reasonable amount.

I have the UILabel and have done all of them. I am finding it hard on how I can do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

(P.S. Please don't post a full code solution as I want to learn how to do it and posting code would just render my learning pointless, any hints and pointers would be the best! Thanks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should convert your array into a string, which you can then assign to the label.

```
label.text = [array componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```